# How to programmatically turn on and configure a hotspot in iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, swift3, wifi

I realize the user can enable a hot spot, set the passkey and it will broadcast as their phones name, e.g Joe's iPhone

But is there away to turn on the hotspot programmatically  in iOS and configure the ssid /wpa key?

For example I have another device searching for ssid `mynetwork` with password `secret` and I would like it to automatically connect to a hotspot my iOS app sets up without the user having to configure their hotspot manually

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Last I heard, it can’t be done without jail breaking. Shy of that, all you can do is ask the user to do it themselves and send them to settings

Answer (score 2):

Currently No API available to create Hotspot.

You could Create new hotspot configurations for open, WEP, WPA/WPA2 personal, WPA/WPA enterprise, and Hotspot 2.0 Wi-Fi networks Using [NEHotspotConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration) Network Extension to connect to Wi-Fi networks.

```
init(ssid:passphrase:isWEP:)
```

> Available iOS 11.0+

Comment: Have you done this before? This does NOT do what I asked. This connects to an existing wifi network. It does NOT enable a personal hotspot other devices can connect to